# I see nothing in my object "PrincipalProduit__c"

Tags: apex, soql

I want to update the information contained in my "var" variable in my "PrincipalProduit__c" object,
using this function

```
public void DMLOperation () {
List <PrincipalProduit__c> letter = getValo ();
List <PrincipalProduit__c> updateList = new List <PrincipalProduit__c> ();
system.debug (letter);
    for (PrincipalProduit__c opps: letter) {
        updateListe.add (opps);
        system.debug (opps);
    }
update (sObject []) updateList;
}
```

But when I make a debug of my valriable "letter" I do not see any value.
what I would like to do is to be able to update the data in my object "principalProduct__c" because in this table the data are incomplete

Here is the code that returns the data that I want to update in my "PrincipalProduit__c" object

```
public List<PrincipalProduit__c> getValo(){
    List<PrincipalProduit__c> searchList = new   List<PrincipalProduit__c>();
    List<PrincipalProduit__c> var = new List<PrincipalProduit__c>();
    for (integer l = 0; l < data.size(); l++) {
        searchList=[SELECT id From PrincipalProduit__c where Email__c=:data[l][0]];
        system.debug(searchList);
        for (PrincipalProduit__c principalProd :searchList) {
            principalProd.CodeAlliance__c = data[l][1];
            var.add(principalProd);
        }               
    }
    system.debug(var);
    return var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 
In

```
List <PrincipalProduit__c> updateList = new List <PrincipalProduit__c> ();
```

the variable is `updateList`, but you are using `updateListe` in the inner part.

```
updateListe.add (opps);
```

Comment: Yes I saw but I still don't see anything